# making div float left and right in the parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to make two divs float left and right in the parent div which is centered.

css

```
body {
margin : 0px;
padding : 0px;
}

#wrapper {
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
border : 1px solid red;

}

#wrapper-header {
width : 1000px;
height : 100%;
border : 1px solid red;
margin : 0px auto;
}   

#wrapper-logo {
width : 250px;
height : 100px;
float : left;
border : 1px solid black;

}

#wrapper-navbar {
width : 250px;
height : 100px;
float : right;
border : 1px solid black;
}
```

and html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper-header">
    <div id="wrapper-logo">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper-navbar">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

but when i am applying the above code it does not comes as i want. please help

Comment: Where's `float` property in your CSS?

Comment: There's no float in your css? so what do you want

Comment: Where are the float props and where is your css for #wrapper-navbar

Comment: code re-edited pls help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want that :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper-header" class="cf"> 
        <div id="wrapper-logo">
            Left
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper-navbar">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css will be :

```
#wrapper-logo {
    float:left;
}

#wrapper-navbar {
    float:right;
}
```

And with a little [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), it'll do the trick. [See here for a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/59PvL/).

[Second example](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/59PvL/5/) with proper width.

Comment: You need to for a nice result.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the float properties:

```
#wrapper-logo {

    width : 250px;
    height : 90px;
    margin : 10px 0px 10px 10px ;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;    
}

#wrapper-navbar{
    float: right; 
    width: 250px;   
}
```

Comment: but when i apply float, it doesnt comes under header element.

Comment: where are you applying the float property?

Comment: It shouldn't come under the header-element, they're inside the header-element.

Comment: @ kenneth pls refer to the soyuka;s live demo the first one and try without clearfix u will get what i want to tell you.

Comment: if don't want to use clearfix than have to give fix height to header portion - check this http://jsfiddle.net/59PvL/6/

Answer (score 0):

Hi have good solution for You in all Your future projects. When i start project i creat a class name `clearfix` which clear all floats and other think. I use this class everytime on parent element which have floats child.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="wrapper-header" class="clearfix">
    <div id="wrapper-logo">
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper-navbar">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
margin : 0px;
padding : 0px;
}
// NEW CLASS //
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
#wrapper {
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
border : 1px solid red;

}

#wrapper-header {
width : 1000px;
height : 100%;
border : 1px solid red;
margin : 0px auto;
}   

#wrapper-logo {
width : 250px;
height : 100px;
float : left;
border : 1px solid black;

}

#wrapper-navbar {
width : 250px;
height : 100px;
float : right;
border : 1px solid black;
}
```

**DEMO**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/WKnbj/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this make your child divs float left and right and it's parent to center of body

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="wrapper-header" class="cf"> 
        <div id="wrapper-logo">
            Left
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper-navbar">
            Right
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css for this

```
wrapper-header{ 
    width:980px; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    overflow:hidden;
}    
#wrapper-logo{  
    float:left; 
}

#wrapper-navbar{
    float:right;
}
```